# Is the strong force a historical accident?

Tags: nuclear-physics, history, strong-force

This is a history-of-physics question.

The  atom was discovered to have a nucleus, a very small core with a positive charge. Then all atoms were found to have roughly multiples of the charge of the basic hydrogen isotope. Besides the hydrogen nucleus, a proton, neutrons were discovered, particles with a little more mass than protons, and isolated neutrons are unstable.

It was proposed that atomic nuclei are collections of protons and neutrons which maintain their individual identities, and inside nuclei the neutrons are stable.

But positive charges repel each other, and the repulsion gets incredibly strong at the tiny distances inside an atomic nucleus. So a strong force was needed, stronger than electric charge, which holds a nucleus together. This force also pushes protons and neutrons apart so they don’t collapse into single points.

What if physicists had imagined that a neutron inside a nucleus might split into a positive and a negative charge? Then things would be different.

Deuterium is a hydrogen atom with a proton and a neutron. If it had one negative charge and two positive charges, at equilibrium with the negative charge halfway between the two positive charges there would be four times the force pulling the protons together than their repulsion pushes them apart. We would still need a force to keep them from collapsing, but no new force to pull them together.

A helium-4 nucleus has two protons and two neutrons. This would be two negative charges and four positive charges. They might form a flattened octahedron, with six corners.

[image: squashed octahedron]

For stationary charges, the two negative charges are balanced when their distance from the center is about 43% that of the positive charges. Closer and they repel, farther and they attract. When their distance is more than 79% then the positive charges repel each other more, and presumably the whole thing would fall apart.

Low-energy alpha particles might attract each other, positive-to-negative corners, and form some sort of crystal structure. Or there could be some other crystal structure in atomic nuclei that have not recently been given a whole lot of energy.

People naturally think that you can’t have a subatomic structure with net positive charge that holds itself together using those charges. But maybe you can, because of inverse square attraction.

Quick handwaving argument – with double the distance you get ¼ the force, and also 4 times the area to put charges in. But actual atomic nuclei may not put four times as many charges in that area.

When they postulated the strong force, did they simply not think of this? Now the strong force is baked into everything, and is assumed to be a fundamental independent force in the universe. All experimental results are consistent with it, because all experimental results are interpreted in terms of its presence. It would be a giant effort to redo physics without it, and probably no one will make that effort.

Or did they consider this and reject it because they found reasons it just did not work?

Comment: Folks certainly contemplated nuclear models with protons+electrons as neutral entities to get nuclear masses correct before the neutron was discovered. There were no good models of just how it all worked out because, well, there isn’t a way to get it to work out.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because is probably a better fit for [hsm.se]

Comment: People considered a planetary model of the atom at the beginning of quantum mechanics. But it quickly became apparent that it wouldn't work. By the time people were thinking about the structure of the nucleus, they would not have been thinking in terms of point mass particles. They would have been thinking in terms of wave functions.

Comment: A good history of the neutron will discuss Fermi-Dirac versus Bose-Einstein statistics, which depends on whether the number of fermions in a nucleus is even or odd, and the rotational spectrum nitrogen. To drink from the firehose, get a copy of Byrne from a library.

Comment: This post (v2) seems more about possible electrons in the nucleus than history per se.

Comment: @JonCuster They did look at nuclear models with protons + electrons? Thank you! Do you know who did it, or where they published? I think it's possible that "there isn't a way to get it to work out" might be that they had a stricter sense of how plausible a theory must be to be acceptable in those days. They had to give up on fitting their preconceptions when nothing worked.

Comment: @StephenG Thank you for the hint!